# How to add multiple origins to the Timing-Allow-Origin customHeader in webapi

Tags: c#, http, asp.net-web-api, custom-headers

Can any one answer my below queries

1. I want to add customHeaders through c# code for all responses.
2. Add multiple origins to the Timing-Allow-Origin customHeader using c#

Comment: It would be awesome if you could share a [mcve] and show us what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

You can send like this

```
Timing-Allow-Origin: value1
Timing-Allow-Origin: value2
Timing-Allow-Origin: value3
```

Answer (score 0):

Plug in a [middleware](https://json.codes/blog/basics-of-writing-owin-middleware/) into the pipeline:

```
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    context.Response.Headers.Add("Time-Allow-Origin", new[] { "value1", "value2", "value3" });

    await next();
});
```

Comment: When i'm adding multiple origins, i can see multiple Timing-Allow-Origin headers with different origins for each request from client side. But i want only requested origin to be added to the Timing-Allow-Origin header even though i have added multiple origins like wise for Allow-Control-Allow-Origin Header (cors).